# Use snakemake's localrules in wildcard specific manner

Tags: snakemake

[`localrules`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules) can be used to run specific rule(s) locally instead of running it as a cluster job. Is it possible to define this in wildcard specific manner, in addition?

For example, in the example below, rule `summer` should be run locally to create file `short_job.txt` and run as a cluster job for file `long_job.txt`.

```py
rule all:
    input: 
        "long_job.txt",
        "short_job.txt",


localrules: summer
rule summer:
    output: 
        "{sample}.txt"
    shell:  
        "touch {output}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this task I would use two separate rules:

```py
rule all:
    input: 
        "long_job.txt",
        "short_job.txt",


rule summer:
    output: 
        "{sample}.txt"
    wildcard_constraints:
        sample=".*long.*"
    shell:  
        "touch {output}"


localrules: summer_local
rule summer_local:
    output: 
        "{sample}.txt"
    wildcard_constraints:
        sample=".*short.*"
    shell:  
        "touch {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my current approach. But with multiple rules, workflow was becoming more and more difficult to read, and hence I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: I guess that the answer is no. At least not with `localrules`: you specify the list of the rules to run locally, and there is no way to run the same rule in both modes.